# how to use Java preprocessors in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

How to use preprocessors in Java like:

```
//#if ooo
        jjj
//#else
                int c=0;
//#endif
```

In Netbeans (they mentioned preprocessor support in the download page)?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your project type, if you use Maven or Ant based project, then you can use [Java Comment Preprocessor](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor) for your project, NetBeans doesn't have any options to connect any preprocessor automatically and you should make it manually in [your pom.xml file](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor/wiki/UsageFromMaven) or [in build.xml](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor/wiki/UsageFromAnt)